# What did Saudi Arabia hope to gain from reintegrating Syria into the Arab League?

Tags: syria, middle-east, saudi-arabia

> A watershed in Syria’s reintegration into the Arab world’s diplomatic
> fold came earlier this year when Saudi Arabia began moving towards
> reconciliation with Damascus.
>
> **Both the February 6 earthquakes and the March 10 Saudi-Iranian
> diplomatic deal accelerated Riyadh’s movement towards renormalisation
> of relations with al-Assad’s regime. It is fair to conclude that
> Syria’s return to the Arab League only became feasible after Saudi
> Arabia changed its position.**

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/5/19/analysis-how-important-is-syrias-return-to-the-arab-league

What did Saudi Arabia hope to gain from reintegrating Syria into the Arab League? They made the move to reintegrate Syria into the Arab League, so why was there such a big shift from Saudi Arabia. What do they have to gain from such a move?

Comment: The article linked to in the question mentions key reasons: pragmatic acceptance that Assad isn't going to step down, led by other countries and encouraged by the earthquake crisis, etc. Other articles like this AP one elaborate similar points: https://apnews.com/article/syria-arab-league-cairo-saudi-arabia-qatar-7de1b30587560531dad1df4eb29f4ef3

Comment: What they gained (e.g. Oct 7 might be related) is less certain than what they might have *hoped* to gain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What they *hoped* to gain [was](https://foreignpolicy.com/2023/06/14/why-arab-countries-are-welcoming-back-assad/) less illicit captagon and less Iranian influence, among other things:

> The spiraling economy and isolation made way for Syria’s illicit captagon trade and cemented the influence of Iran and Russia.
>
> A 2022 report from the New Lines Institute on Jordan’s attempts to normalize relations with Syria detailed the challenges of those efforts, particularly in relation to the captagon trade. Though accurate details about captagon production and trade are difficult to determine, the drug likely brings in billions for the regime. Assad and his network, including many members of his family, control captagon production; then, smugglers take it through a variety of routes, including through Jordan, to markets in the Gulf countries.
>
> “What the actual figure is is difficult to estimate, but I would say [what] the Assad regime gets to their own pockets is, I believe, no less than a billion dollars, while the market value of that industry could be over $10 billion,” Karam Shaar, an independent analyst on Syria’s politics and economy, said. “However you look at it, this actually exceeds Syria’s legal exports. That’s playing a pivotal role in the way countries in the region are looking at Syria and how to deal with it.”
>
> The counterfeit captagon makes its way throughout the region. It travels primarily through Jordan and Lebanon, but Saudi Arabia reported the highest number of seizures from 2015 to 2019—in 2019, nearly 146 million tablets, compared to 23 million in Jordan, the next highest reported amount, according to a 2021 UN report. Though Arab nations may hope to control the illicit captagon trade through negotiations with Damascus and investing in a licit Syrian economy, there’s no reason to believe that the Assad regime is willing to give up what has become lucrative business, should widespread normalization be on the horizon.
>
> Wealthy Gulf nations and the countries that rely on them may also try to blunt Iran’s influence over Syria and in the region, by mending ties with Damascus and working with Tehran. But, as Aron Lund, a fellow at Century International and Middle East analyst at the Swedish Defense Research Agency said, this isn’t the first time they’ve made such attempts.

(And yeah captagon [has been](https://www.sciencedirect.com/sdfe/pdf/download/eid/1-s2.0-S0015736894729091/first-page-pdf) pretty popular in Saudi Arabia for decades, despite the official prohibition.)

Whether either [hope] panned out, it's hard to say [for now].

> But, as Aron Lund, a fellow at Century International and Middle East analyst at the Swedish Defense Research Agency said, this isn’t the first time they’ve made such attempts.
>
> “There were repeated attempts to ‘flip’ Syria, before the war, to move away from Iran and into the Saudi-led sphere,” Lund said in an interview. But the nations attempting that maneuver “were just frustrated, time and time again, and I think probably they realize at this point, first of all, that Assad is not going to budge on core issues like Iran. He needs Iran; he’s not going to step away from Iran. And he’s not going to be a reliable negotiator that delivers everything that he promises to do.”

Anyhow, it's part of the wider Saudi effort to seek a modus vivendi with Iranian allies/proxies, Houthis included, after failing to defeat them militarily (either directly or by sponsoring their own proxies.)

Comment: More on captagon in SA https://arabcenterdc.org/resource/the-captagon-problem-in-saudi-arabia-and-other-gulf-states/ and https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/02/middleeast/saudi-drug-capital-mime-intl/index.html